# Traversing arrays output

Tags: tcl

Can someone help me to figure out why the result will display Thursday as first output?
Im using Execute Tcl Online (Tcl v8.6.6)

```
array set days {
    1 Monday
    2 Tuesday
    3 Wednesday
    4 Thursday
    5 Friday
    6 Saturday
    7 Sunday
}
foreach {n day} [array get days] {
    puts "$n -> $day"
}

Output 
$tclsh main.tcl
4 -> Thursday
5 -> Friday
1 -> Monday
6 -> Saturday
2 -> Tuesday
7 -> Sunday
3 -> Wednesday
```

Answer (score 1):

> Array keys are not ordered. It isn't straight-forward to get values out of an array in the same order that they were set. One common alternative is to get the names and then order them. In contrast, values in a dictionary are ordered.

[Wikisource](https://wiki.tcl-lang.org/page/array)

If you want to get them sorted, you will need to sort the keys, or alternatively use something other than an array that will keep the order of the elements you are inserting in the array, like a list.

Sorting example using [`lsort`](http://tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/lsort.htm):

```
foreach {name} [lsort -integer [array names days]] {
    puts "$name -> $days($name)"
}
```

Results:

```
1 -> Monday
2 -> Tuesday
3 -> Wednesday
4 -> Thursday
5 -> Friday
6 -> Saturday
7 -> Sunday
```

Answer (score 1):

Arrays are not ordered, but *dictionaries* do maintain the **insertion** order:

```
set days [dict create {*}{
    1 Monday
    2 Tuesday
    3 Wednesday
    4 Thursday
    5 Friday
    6 Saturday
    7 Sunday
}]
dict for {key val} $days {puts "$key -> $val"}
```

```
1 -> Monday
2 -> Tuesday
3 -> Wednesday
4 -> Thursday
5 -> Friday
6 -> Saturday
7 -> Sunday
```